# P-Channel MOSFET Reverse Polarity Protection

Tags: mosfet

why is it always that a P-Channel MOSFET is used with reverse polarity protection?

Can we just use an N-Channel MOSFET?

Comment: Do you how the p channel mosfet works for reverse polarity protection ? If so, can those same attributes/ characteristics be used with an N channel ?

Comment: I'm a beginner when it comes to MOSFETS. I have seen some videos where they use a P-Channel, but non of them explained why. Does any of this have to do with the body diode?

Comment: You can, but you'd have to put it in the GROUND line instead of the POWER line.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the diode.   A MOSFET only cares what the relative voltage of GATE to SOURCE is.   Look close at the circuits you found, consider what voltage will appear on the MOSFET.    For an N channel, if the GATE is more positive than the SOURCE, it will turn ON.   If not, it turns off.     For a P Channel, it's opposite... If the gate is MORE NEGATIVE than the source, it turns on.

Comment: Relevant question: [How can I add N channel MOSFET for reverse polarity protection?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/261949/how-can-i-add-n-channel-mosfet-for-reverse-polarity-protection)

Comment: because the n-chan would drop a lot of voltage between D and S; basically the same as Vgs(th). Ex: 12v going into D+G would result in 9v coming out of S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an N-channel MOSFET for reverse polarity protection, as attested to by these SE questions:

- [NMOS FET selection for reverse polarity protection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34915/nmos-fet-selection-for-reverse-polarity-protection)
- [How can I add N channel MOSFET for reverse polarity protection?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/261949/how-can-i-add-n-channel-mosfet-for-reverse-polarity-protection)

A lot of designers like to keep the grounds of their power supply and application circuit at the same potential and using an N-channel MOSFET means you introduce an element between them. Any return ground return current will increase the separation between these two potentials.

For a battery operated device this shouldn't be an issue, but perhaps the habit remains. After all, a diode for reverse polarity protection may also be used on the high side or low side, but in designs you  always see it on the high side.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense now.